# How to write frames extracted from opencv videocapture to kinesis video stream

Tags: opencv, video, stream, amazon-kinesis

I am reading `kinesis` video stream and performing aws face recognition. However I have to perform tasks like creating rectangle and other post-processing tasks by `OpenCV` after `AWS face reCognition`. So, I captured kinesis video with `Boto3 library` and give input to OpenCV library and performed my operation. Now I am not sure how to write the frame back to kinesis after performing the operation.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061634/boto3-kinesis-video-getmedia-and-opencv) is the reference link showing how to read data from Kinesis video stream. Instead of `imshow` I need to write back frames to kinesis video stream. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Other alternative would be to render the bounding boxes with the video and stream it back to another kinesis video stream using the stream producer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a published example to read Kinesis Video data, retrieve AWS Rekognition json output, draw bounding boxes on top of rekognized faces and render it locally or create a new derivative kinesis video stream. Unfortunately it's in java though.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideo---rekognition-examples